# What is 'other-table, column-dependent, dynamic table status'?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm trying to sketch out a database template on some design paper, and I'm having trouble with dependencies.

Users submit content to the website for viewing, and the content is given priorities based on what kind of content it is.  I also would like the priorities, however, to be set by user.  Basically, if person A is person B's friend, the content submitted by person A is high priority for person B.  Person C is not person A's friend, so the content is low priority for person C in this medium.

I don't even know where to begin.  Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.  I think that this is a MySQL question; however, I am using PHP as the server-side scripting language, and I'm wondering if the math makes it so that there isn't a solution via MySQL.

I'm thinking about just using a region for friend content and not messing with priorities, currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you track what you need it shouldn't be problem, the trick will be in writing the Sql. For instance if you had the following table structure

```
person
------
id
name
otherstuff

person_releationship
-------------------
person_a_id
person_b_id
relationship_type_id

relationship_type
-------------------------
id
content_priority

content
--------------
id
stuff
person_id
user_priority
```

You could write the following statement which would retrieve all the content associated with a person, excluding their own content, prioritized by content_priority

```
SELECT
    stuff
FROM 
    content c
    INNER JOIN person p
    ON c.person_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN person_releationship pr
    ON p.person_id = pr.person_a_id 
       or p.person_id = pr.person_b_id 
    INNER JOIN relationship_type rt
    ON pr.relationship_type_id = rt.id
WHERE
    p.id = "A"
    and c.person_id <> "A"
ORDER BY
    rt.content_priority, 
    c.user_priority
```

If you want you could also use weighted priority so the ORDER BY could be

```
ORDER BY
rt.content_priority *  c.user_priority
```

You should note that this SQL and table design is independent of the RDBMS and the web technology.

Comment: So, if the content has a default priority that's overridden by a user relationship, do I just need to choose which one is more important, or should I inter-mix the column by a formula:

    content
    --------------
    id
    stuff
    person_id
    content_priority

Comment: Well that's up to you. Do you want the highest priority from an non-friend to always be lower than the lowest priority of a friend?

Comment: I'm not sure what RDSM.  That's interesting about weighted priority.  Thank you.

Comment: oops I meant [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)

Comment: Well, what I would like to do is have the content that is high priority to the site mix in with content that is highly personalized on a kind of tit-for-tat system.  Two friend-content views followed by two site priorities views.  Even if friend content is high site priority, it's kind of a treat.  So, if it's both friend and priority content, it won't count as a priority view.  This way, I hope to encourage growth community growth while maintaining a healthy society.

Comment: I think it:s a very interesting solution, to weight.  If I weight, I can do a 0-100 priority scale and multiply or divide it by other fields accordingly.  I'm a little sketchy that it won't work out as planned, but it may be a perfect solution.  Thanks, again.